# How to do status-quo probit analysis in R

Tags: r, probit

I am wanting to estimate the median age of menarche. I have the age of girls and whether or not they were currently menstruating.

From the literature review, I see that a probit analysis is used for this 'status quo' technique. But I have not been able to find a clear example of how to use probit analysis to obtain a median age in R.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that for probit model,  $P(Y=1|X)=\Phi(aX+b)$

using R programming, we can obtain $a$ and $b$ using maximum likelihood.

For median, we have to solve for $$0.5 = \Phi(ax+b)$$

$$\Phi^{-1}(0.5) = ax+b$$

$$0 = ax+b$$

$$x=-\frac{b}a$$

Here are some codes to do so in R.

```
  probX = function(p, model) {
  data.frame(prob=p, 
             xval = (qnorm(p) - coef(model)[1])/coef(model)[2])
}


age <-runif(200, 10, 30)
cdf_function <- function(x) {
  pnorm(x, mean = mean(age), sd = sd(age))
}

# Apply the CDF to ages to get probabilities
probabilities <- cdf_function(age)

# Generate a binary outcome based on random numbers and probabilities
y <- as.integer(runif(length(age)) < probabilities)

print(age)
print(y)
probit_model <- glm(y ~ age, family = binomial("probit"))
print(probit_model)


# Fit probit model
d = probX(c(0.5), probit_model)
plot_data <- data.frame(age = age, y = y, predicted_prob = predict(probit_model, type = "response"))
rng = range(age) + diff(range(age))*c(-0.02,0.02)

# Plot the data, probit model, and probabilities
p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=age, y=y)) + geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="glm", color="green", se=FALSE, 
              method.args = list(family=binomial)) + 
  geom_segment(data=d, aes(x=xval, xend=xval, y=0, yend=prob), colour="red") +
  geom_segment(data=d, aes(x=rng[1], xend=xval, y=prob, yend=prob), colour="red") +
  geom_text(data=d, aes(label=round(xval, 1), x=xval, y=-0.03), size=3, colour="red") +
  theme_bw()

show(p)
```

and the figure is as follows:

[image]